# How do I store a cookie value as a String?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cookies

I am having problems storing a cookie value as a string for an iPhone project. Currently, I am retrieving the value of the cookies this way:

```
NSString *somevalue;

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies)
{
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ : Value: %@, Expires: %@", cookie.name, cookie.value, cookie.expiresDate);
    somevalue = cookie.value;
}
```

Now, in theory this SHOULD store cookie.value as string 'somevalue'. I can do an NSLog of 'somevalue' and it retrieves the correct value.

However, when I pass this through to:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fullUrl]];
[request setPostValue:someValue forKey:@"profile_id"];
[request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"start"];
[request setPostValue:@"10" forKey:@"end"];
```

and then check the response, it is passing in the entire cookie (this is what it looks like):

```
a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%221fcd876dc0240ac4a59f3630b8f630fe%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%220.0.0.0%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A50%3A%22Doubletake+1.0+%28iPhone+Simulator%3B+iPhone+OS+3.1.3%3B%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%221276270293%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22email%22%3Bs%3A18%3A%22tim%40domain.com%22%3B%7D5f9c567d5832013183d511dba8910cf3
```

Is the value actually getting stored? Why is this happening?

Comment: Not enough code to figure out where you've gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep an object around past the current method invocation (or often just past the lifetime of its owner), you need to claim ownership of it with `retain`. See the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for a full explanation.

Comment: Chuck, I hear what you are saying, but when I do an:

NSLog(@"Name: %@", cookie.name);

And then store the value of cookie.name into a String, they come out as two totally different values (The NSLog is '48', which is a stored variable, and the other variable displays the entire cookie)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *somevalue;

for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies)
{
    NSLog(@"Name: %@ : Value: %@, Expires: %@", cookie.name, cookie.value, cookie.expiresDate);
    somevalue = cookie.value;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.